# Reading the example code output from example( ) run on R help files

Tags: r

I am having trouble human-parsing the output from some R example code when it is run by `example( )`. For instance, when I run  `example("withCallingHandlers")`, I see output preceded by "`wthClH>`", which appears to me to be the example code, and output preceded by "`[1]`", which seems to be the console output that the code produces. So far so good.

But then there are lines preceded by  "`wthClH> ##`" or "`wthClH> ##D`".  Both of these seem to be part of blocks of code that are labeled "Not run:" But I do not understand any basis for the decisions to run or not run particular example lines -- sometimes it has a "Not run" line, and then a few lines later runs almost the same line.

And then there are lines that are enclosed in pointy brackets, like: `<simpleError: test error >`. I am taking these as sort-of meta-comments, that are even more commented than the code comments marked `##`. But I am not at all confident that I am correct in this.

Are these help-example typography conventions explained anywhere? And if so, how should I have been expected to find it, given that, unless I have somehow overlooked it, there is no mention of any of these conventions in the help for either `example( )` or the help for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.

- `wthClH>` is a modified "R prompt", demonstrating each line that the example code is showing and optionally executing. Every line that is used/demoed, whether actual code or just a comment, is prefaced by this. It is the normal R prompt

  ```
  >
  ```

  but specifically for example code. I suspect it's not `>` in order to clearly separate its sample code execution from anything on your console immediately before calling `example(...)`.
- `wthClH> ##` (with or without a "D") is merely a comment, ignored and not executed. Imagine what would happen if you typed `## hello world` directly on the R command line, so that it looked like

  ```
  > ## hello world
  ```

  ... that is, nothing happens, it is merely a comment.

  Sometimes it is human words, sometimes it is R code that is not intended to be executed but still shown as a possible example. The "why" of why it is "not run" might be that it is merely working up to a full call, allowing you to try each component manually; often, in R man-pages (for "help"), code might be included in the "dontrun" block because it might rely on things that may not be present on test computers and/or user computers.
- most other output, such as

  ```
  [1] "Hello"
  <simpleError: test error>
  ```

  and

  ```
   [1] "Hello"
  <simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): fred>
  ```

  and

  ```
  Warning in withCallingHandlers({ : A
  [1] 3
  ```

  are the output of the commands executed; only those commands not prefaced with comments (one or more `#`) are executed.

I agree that these typography decorators (`wthClH>`) are not strictly necessary.

Comment: So the ones in "<  >"s are a printing convention, not of examples, but of the exception system? Regular error messages don't do that.

Comment: For the most part, yes. If you run `simpleError('hello')`, you'll see that. If you run `dput(simpleError('hello'))`, you'll see that what the function returns is actually just a list with a specific class applied. Using R's "S3" method dispatch, you can see that `print.condition` (called b/c the list included class `"condition"`) literally `cat`s the brackets and some other stuff to the console. But it isn't actually producing a `stop`-like error. If you look at `simpleError` (the function source), you'll see that it produces a `list`, nothing more. `stop` does much more.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please "accept" it. If not, edit your question to explain what else is needed.